# Push values onto an associative array

Tags: javascript, push, associative-array

I have the following code I've created for a student I mentor and I'm wondering if anyone can think of an easier way, or method that already exists? I'm also interested in learning how to create plugins in javascript, but forgot how/can't find it on google.

Anyway, here's the code...

```
window.addEventListener('load', function()
{
    for(var i = 0; i < document.forms[0].length; i++)
    {
        document.forms[0].elements[i].checked = false;
    }   
}, false);

function formHandler()
{
    valArray = new Array();
    toppArray = new Array();
    var theForm = document.forms[0];

    for(var i = 0; i < theForm.length; i++)
    {
        theValue = theForm.elements[i].value;
        if(theForm.elements[i].checked == true)
        {
            if(theForm.elements[i].type == 'checkbox' && theForm.elements[i].name == 'myChBx')
            {
                appendArr(toppArray, theForm.elements[i].value);
                appendArr(valArray, toppArray, 'topping');  
            }else
            {
                appendArr(valArray, theValue);  
            }
        }
    }
}

function appendArr(array, value, keyVal = '')
{
    if(keyVal != '')
    {
        array[keyVal] = value;
    }else
        array[array.length] = value;
}
```

Ok, now a brief explanation on what this code does. In php I know you can append a value onto an array using something like

```
$array[] = $value;
```

but I've read several places how you must use objects to create an associative array in javascript. In a way I guess I've done that, but I managed, using the array object.

The purpose of this is to take values from a simple radio and checkbox form such as this one...

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./appendArr.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        Radio 1:<input type="radio" name="myRdo" id="rdo" value="radio 1" onclick="formHandler();" />
        Radio 2:<input type="radio" name="myRdo" id="rdo" value="radio 2" onclick="formHandler();" />
        Radio 3:<input type="radio" name="myRdo" id="rdo" value="radio 3" onclick="formHandler();" />
        <br />
        Checkbox 1:<input type="checkbox" name="myChBx" id="myChBx" value="Checkbox 1" onclick="formHandler();" />
        Checkbox 2:<input type="checkbox" name="myChBx" id="myChbx" value="Checkbox 2" onclick="formHandler();" />
        Checkbox 3:<input type="checkbox" name="myChBx" id="myChbx" value="Checkbox 3" onclick="formHandler();" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="button" " value="Button" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and store them in one array with one of the values of that array being an associative array called toppings; so some values in the array will be single variables, while others will be a collection of single variables.

Anyway... I probably just spent an hour on this for nothing, but I come here to learn, so please don't troll. Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to store custom properties in an `Array`?  Are you sure you don't want an `Object`?

Comment: The girl I'm working with is creating a pizza order form, the radio buttons are supposed to be the specialty orders (Meat Lovers, Veggie, etc...) and the toppings (Pepperoni, Pineappe, etc...) The way she has coded it; every time an element is clicked on, it is added to that array. So I created a way for her to be able to click on a topping and have it automatically appended to the array she's maintaining; if that makes any sense.

Comment: As a side note... the array itself is in a defined Object, Pizza.

The above code is me trying to develop a function for her to easily use.

Also, I just went off what she had already started, because for the most part it works... and I don't want to scrap all of her code, when it's so close to the deadline.

Comment: @BrianAllanWest Mixing array semantics (numeric indexes and `.length`) with object semantics (string-named properties) is not a good habit to get into.  JavaScript arrays are significantly different things than PHP arrays.  In particular, the `length` property **only** includes numerically-indexed properties.

Comment: The code works and does what I had intended it to do... whether or not it is proper, or good coding practice, at this time does not matter to me, because it is not my project, it is a new javascript programmer's work. My intent was to see if anyone could offer any other sort of solution to the problem.

Comment: @BrianAllanWest ah well that's sort of what I meant: the "other solution" I'd offer would be to stick with either all-string or all-numeric object properties.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has no associative arrays, it has "arrays" which are indexed lists, and it has "objects" which are key:value containers. This also doesn't really seem relevant to what you're asking, so... what's the actual question you need answered? "How do I do $arr[] = $val in JavaScript"? If so, it's push(), as in:

```
["a","b","c"].push("d") // result: ["a","b","c","d"]
```

If that wasn't your question, please edit your original post because it's entirely unclear what you actually want to know.